# How do I delete the 32k errored document?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am having some documents. If I try to open the document then it shows error like "field is too large 32k or view's column & selection formulas are too large"

Whenever I try to delete the document, I am getting the same error. I am not able to delete.

Okay we can try to get the document via backend, But there, I can not get the document handle.

Whatever I try to search then the document collection count is 0.

> Important:- I am using Notes 6.5.2.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Can you create a view with fewer documents and then delete from there?

Comment: are you sure you have no any preview mode or query document delete code? I do not think deletion documents with items more then 32kb should be a problem.

Comment: I think @dmytro is onto something. If the preview pane is open, even by just a couple of pixels, formulas in the document will fire when you select the document in the view and that could throw the 32k error.  Make sure that the pane is completely closed down.  If that's not the problem, then a querydocumentscript event script (in the Database Script) could be throwing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You may create new replica of the database, currupted documents won't be copied. Also you may try to use ScanEZ tool from Ytria.

Comment: load compact -c as well, but I don't recall if that option is in R6.

Comment: Tasks compact&fixup may help but may not help. It worse to try before using other methods.

Comment: Yes you are correct, But we are maintaining more replica copies in different countries. The thing is that one server has the document that we can not open or delete. In some other server it does not have the document. We need to delete the 32K errored document. Is it any third party tool is there? or Can we do it in script itself?

Comment: You can't do it in script. Only by Notes C API. Try to use Ytria's ScanEZ tool to delete such documents (see http://techlab.ytria.com/855/uncategorized/lotus-notes-32k-error-help/). Try to use their lite version before.

Answer (score 1):

"Okay we can try to get the document via backend, But there, I can not get the document handle."

Could you post the code you are using? 
I don't see why the following code would not work:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim col As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim deleteDoc List as NotesDocument

Set db = session.Currentdatabase
'*** Get collection of selected documents
Set col = db.UnprocessedDocuments
'*** Loop through selected documents
Set doc = col.GetFirstDocument
Do Until doc Is Nothing
    '*** Add document to list to delete later
    Set deleteDoc(doc.UniversalID) = doc
    Set doc = col.GetNextDocument(doc)
Loop

'*** Delete all documents in list from database
ForAll d in deleteDoc
    Call d.Remove(True)
End ForAll
```

Comment: Hi I am using NotesView.GetDocumentByKey method, Code is working fine for all documents. Here if I give the UNID or NotesID. It is throwing invalid Document ID error. I am able to see the document. But I can not get the handle of the document. Even I could not read that document.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may want to change the field that causing you headache to rich text since the limit for rich text field is slightly bigger that normal text field. The limit for rich text filed is limited only by available disk space up to 1GB

Comment: Thanks,Yes I understand the problem, Why is it happening? But I am not able to delete these documents.

Comment: It's because data that been handled by the affected field already exceed it's limit. 

See the workaround from IBM:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21087474

Comment: Your information is wealthy. But this is not helping for me. Because I am not able to get the document handle. Whatever i try to refresh or update the document or compute the document via backend. Result remains nothing. From IBM Support information, How can I find which item causing the problem without viewing the document property? I guess that the problem is because of one Rich text field. From the IBM Support, Rich text field does not cause anything. Also we can not view the rich text data in view column. My requirement is very simple, I NEED TO DELETE THE DOCUMENT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply delete the problem field on a corrupt document, and then delete the document? You can try to do the following:

1- create an agent set to run on selected documents with the following formula:

```
FIELD corruptfield := @DeleteField;
```

2 - select a problem document in a view and run the agent

3 - if that does not error out, then try to manually delete the document from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me :

1/ Get the Note ID of the doc with DocViewer

There may be many other ways to get the NoteID, but it just showed up when I tried to send the doc through **DocViewer**, the well known free tool
https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Document%20Viewer/summary

2/ Remove the doc with Notes C API

I followed the advice of *pstr*, and quickly found out this script 
http://www.nsftools.com/tips/ApiStublessDelete.lss
Just aim it at the good database, with the Note ID, and it does the trick !!

I tried to change the script in order to not remove the deletion stub (I wished the removal would replicate over my cluster and local replica). But you fall back on the 32k error ! So you have to apply the deletion over every replica (or recreate the replicas of course).